# problema con warning 4702: no se puede tener acceso al código

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Estoy tratando de actualizar unos src viejos a visual 2015, pero no consigo dar con una buena sintaxis.

Tengo estos dos métodos que me tiran:

> W4702: no se puede tener acceso al código

El código (comentado más abajo):

```cpp
void CMisc::GetPoint(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, int * pX, int * pY, int * pError)
{   int dx, dy, x_inc, y_inc, error, index;
    int iResultX, iResultY;
    if ((x0 == x1) && (y0 == y1))
    {   *pX = x0;
        *pY = y0;
        *pError = 0;
        return;
    }
    error = *pError;
    iResultX = x0;
    iResultY = y0;
    dx = x1 - x0;
    dy = y1 - y0;
    x_inc = -1;
    if (dx >= 0) { x_inc = 1; }
    else { dx = -dx; }
    y_inc = -1;
    if (dy >= 0) { y_inc = 1; }
    else { dy = -dy; }
    if (dx > dy)
    {   for (index = 0; index <= dx; index++)
        {   error += dy;
            if (error>dx)
            {   error -= dx;
                iResultY += y_inc;
            }
            iResultX += x_inc;
            goto CALC_OK;
        }
    }
    else
    {   for (index = 0; index <= dy; index++)
        {   error += dx;
            if (error>0)
            {   error -= dy;
                iResultX += x_inc;
            }
            iResultY += y_inc;
            goto CALC_OK;
    }   }
CALC_OK:;
    *pX = iResultX;
    *pY = iResultY;
    *pError = error;
}


void CMisc::GetPoint2(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, int * pX, int * pY, int * pError, int iCount)
{   int dx, dy, x_inc, y_inc, error, index;
    int iResultX, iResultY, iCnt = 0;
    if ((x0 == x1) && (y0 == y1))
    {   *pX = x0;
        *pY = y0;
        *pError = 0;
        return;
    }
    error = *pError;
    iResultX = x0;
    iResultY = y0;
    dx = x1 - x0;
    dy = y1 - y0;
    x_inc = -1;
    if (dx >= 0) { x_inc = 1; }
    else { dx = -dx; }
    y_inc = -1;
    if (dy >= 0) { y_inc = 1; }
    else { dy = -dy; }
    if (dx>dy)
    {   for (index = 0; index <= dx; index++)
        {   error += dy;
            if (error > dx)
            {   error -= dx;
                iResultY += y_inc;
            }
            iResultX += x_inc;
            iCnt++;
            if (iCnt >= iCount) goto CALC_OK;
        }
    }else
    {   for (index = 0; index <= dy; index++)
        {   error += dx;
            if (error > dy)
            {   error -= dy;
                iResultX += x_inc;
            }
            iResultY += y_inc;
            iCnt++;
            if (iCnt >= iCount) goto CALC_OK;
    }   }
CALC_OK:;
    *pX = iResultX;
    *pY = iResultY;
    *pError = error;
}
```

No sé exactamente cómo funciona, pero en las lineas: `if (dx > dy)`
aparece el error W4702. Corrijanme si me equivoco, el bucle for va a dar vueltas hasta que `index <= dx`, en caso de que el if salga por el true, y sino por el false, `index <= dy`; ¿correcto?

Mi duda es la siguiente:
¿A medida que el for da vueltas, se va a estar modificando constantemente los punteros de salida? Es decir, ¿hasta que el for no cumpla la condición?

Mi otra duda es:
¿Ya nomás a la primera vuelta se ejecuta el goto y se rompe el for? No estoy seguro cómo funciona el goto.

Probé algo al cachetazo de sacar el goto y los warning desaparecen... pero no me convence.

Lo que más me interesa es quitar el goto.

Comment: Sustituye `goto CALC_OK` por `break` y, al menos en teoría, debería solucionarse. esos `goto` no parecen tener demasiado sentido, al menos no sin poder depurar el código. Si revisas el código te darás cuenta de que los `for` son confusos porque no van a poder ejecutar más de una iteración... se nota que es código legado.